# How to set tabindex on Primefaces accordion tab

Tags: java, jquery

Does anyone know how to set the tabindex to the Primeface accordion panel tab. like

```
<p:accordionPanel tabindex="6" autoHeight="false" >
    <p:tab title="tab1"></p:tab>
    <p:tab title="tab2"></p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

I'm currently use the primeface version 3.4.2 and the accordion tab always set the tabindex to -1.  Is there a way to do change the accordion tab to take the input tabindex from the  tag?
                            >

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there no tabindex on accordion panel nor on tabs. In PrimeFaces doc there's nothing about a tabindex on accordion. I guess PF accordion is not an HTML field (input) or link (a), (I would say a div with css), so tabindex doesn't really make sense.
I'm afraid you have to customise the accordion component but I'm also afraid it's not possible to manage the tabindex anyway if it is not on a "HTML 1.0 component user can interact with".
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

The pass-through-solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666472/custom-html-tag-attributes-are-not-rendered-by-jsf) might help at least for setting tab indices to the tabs themselves